What buried utility line would be 1/8" and can I protect it?
Found a 1/8" yellow wire 18" below soil surface while hand digging in backyard or a garden. It wasn't marked when I called 811, and I have no idea what it could be.
I didn't damage it, but I'm concerned that plant roots could.
How can I identify it? Since it's not in the easement, I think 811 doesn't take responsibility for marking or identifying.
And is there a way I can just wrap a 5 ft section of it to protect it from semi-fibrous roots? (I'm not planting holly, boxwood, a tree, etc- but it's so small, and I have no clue what it is. It appears the wifi line from my house was marked elsewhere.) That would be easier than relocatong my project.
It couldn't be related to the gas line in some way, could it? I think it's near the gas line.

Can’t say for sure, but sometimes tracer lines are yellow… look to the above-ground ends of your gas line.

Does it point/line up to anything?  A street pole, meter/s on the house, phone/cable box.  Most cables/pipes  usually go in a straight line from something to something.

Thank you, i think it must be a tracer wire that's just straying a bit from the gas line! I think they're supposed to be taped to the PVC around the gas at intervals to protect the tracer wire, but idk what kind of tape they use?

That does indeed sound like the tracer/indicator for a gas line, which is probably just below or alongside the wire. They are often laid above or to the side of the line, and not tight to the pipe.
Since the tracer is required to be grounded (which I realize sounds odd for a wire in the ground), you should see it emerge with your gas line and be attached to a metal fixture.
There's no need to protect it since it doesn't actually carry current. If you want to prevent damage, though, just don't install anything that would interfere with tracing equipment. Plastic is probably fine.

It could be fibre for internet (if floppy and non metallic) but I would not expect direct burial on that, (instead PEX microduct 3/8").
It could be an old invisible dog fence (especially if it holds its shape like metal wire does) although 18" is pretty deep to bury that.
To protect.  you could slit a plastic conduit, or PEX etc and put that around it , or bury a "buried wires"  notification board above it etc.

A little more detail: An invisible fence typically consists of twisted-pair wire running from the electronics out to the edge of the area being fenced. At that point it splits and a single conductor runs around the edge of the area. For a rectangular lot you would usually find the single conductor within a few feet of the lot line and running parallel to it.

they may have wanted part of the yard for humans only -  no digging in the strawberry bed  etc,  but yes the single wires will usually be parallel to a boundary or some other significant feature
